# How many points at infinity in Artin-Schreier type curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $Y$ be an affine curve over a perfect (yet not necessarily algebraically closed) field $k$ given by
$$y^p+a(x)y=b(x)$$
(abs. irreducible) with $p$ a prime number. Now one can normalize $k[1/x]$ in the function field of $Y$ to obtain the point(s) at infinity.

1. What would be an 'if and only if'-condition on $a$ and $b$ for $Y$ having exactly one point at infinity in the normalization?

As this seems to be hard to answer, maybe one can say something like this:

2. Assuming $\deg a$ is somewhat smaller than $\deg b$, say 
   $$\deg a < \frac{p-1}p \deg b$$
   then $Y$ has one point at infinity if $p$ does not divide $\deg b$ (?)
3. There is another problem when the polynomials are not monic. I don't see how to normalize $y^p=2x^p$ without having the $p$th roots of $2$ in $k$. So do I need (2.) and $b$ monic?